# Increasing Board VCC with op amp

Tags: led, operational-amplifier, coin-cell

I am trying to make a small board with an RGB LED on it. I would like to power the board with a nice small 12mm coin cell (3V). However the typical forward voltages of the RGB LED (and minimums) are slighly higher (~3.5V).

Would it be kosher to use a non-inverting op amp circuit to bump up the VCC slightly to achieve the proper forward voltage for the LED? Will this damage the battery or cause it to die faster?

Comment: Opamps aren't magic. They can't give a higher output voltage than whatever you put on their supply pins.

Comment: @brhans So boost converters are magic?

Comment: @ThePhoton - No, and op-amps aren't boost converters. Read the question - the OP's assumption is obvious.

Comment: @brhans Boost converters aren't op-amps, but your comments implied a device would have to be magic to output a higher voltage than it has available as input. The reason op-amps can't do that isn't because they aren't magic, it's because they don't have any significant energy storage devices (inductors or capacitors) configured to do it.

Comment: @ThePhoton - because if they did they'd be boost converters, not opamps, and the OP is asking about opamps, not boost converters. Again - read the question and see the OP's implicit assumption that an **opamp** can output a voltage higher than its supply rails.

Comment: @brhans, Yes, but they'd have to be boost converters (or switched capacitor converters, or whatever). But they wouldn't have to be magic.

Comment: @brhans, consider a learner doesn't know what an op-amp is or isn't. They ask a question about it. You tell them it would have to be magic to produce an output above its power supply voltage. Then three months later they find out about boost converters --- should they think boost converters or magic or should they think you were not informing them accurately about what is and isn't magic?

Comment: @ThePhoton - yes if they were some other thing the OP didn't ask about they wouldn't have to be magic. The place to give the OP an in-depth education in something he didn't ask about, but might lead to solving his implied question would be in an answer to his question, not in a comment. Or perhaps he'd be inspired to ask a new question about boosting his circuit's supply voltage (which imo would be more appropriate since the answers would then match the question instead of answering a question which wasn't asked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op amps can't increase their output voltage higher than their supply voltage, so you'd have to have a separate higher voltage supply as well, which defeats the purpose. Look into a buck/boost regulator or Ćuk converter instead.

Comment: +1 for suggesting an inductive SMPS, but I think I'd suggest a simple buck converter circuit. he only needs step-up capability here, so no reason to use the more complex topologies.

Comment: A buck converter can't do step-up! And with a 3V battery driving LEDs... you'll need both step-up and step-down depending on the LED being driven and the amount of charge used from the battery.

Comment: ahhh crap, thanks. I typed buck while thinking boost. Sorry about that. however, I think boost would work so long as the led "color" voltages aren't very far below the coin cell's 3V. However, I can also see where a cuk could be made more efficient by "switching off" between bursts in some setups.

Comment: Honestly, I just have a thing for Ćuk converters. I love the way all their magnetics interact and cancel out some of the ripple. You could do it easily with a buck/boost or just a boost converter, probably.